# How can I change the primary domain on Google Apps?

Tags: google-workspace, domain

I have a Google Apps for your domain account for my domain which we will call `DomainA`

I have since replaced that domain with `DomainB` which is set up in the Google Apps account as an alias.

Since I want to let `DomainA` expire at some point in the future, I would like to change my primary domain to `DomainB` in my Google Apps account with `DomainA` as an alias.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do NOT use google apps account with an expired domain just because you are getting it for free. Your account can be compromised via CNAME records. Related http://techcrunch.com/2011/05/18/security-breach-heres-how-expired-domains-expose-you-to-embarrassment-and-theft/

Comment: I am aware of that. Google Apps is the sole reason I have been reneewing the domain for the last few years.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT**

My original answer is obsolete at this time. See [Change your primary domain from the Admin console](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7009324?hl=en)

Thanks [Rubén](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n) for the heads up!

> Unfortunately, you can't do this without having to create a new Google
>   Apps account.
>
> From [this Google Apps article][1]:
>
> > You can associate additional domain
> >     names with your Google Apps account,
> >     as separate domains or as domain
> >     aliases for your primary domain.
> >     However, at this time you can't change
> >     which domain is your primary domain.
> >     Your only option for a new primary
> >     domain is to create a new account and
> >     migrate your data to the new account.
>
> In summary, for you to make `DomainB` your primary domain and
>   `DomainA` as an alias you would have to:
>
> - Remove `DomainB` as an alias from your existing Google Apps account
> - Create a new Google Apps account with `DomainB` as the primary domain
> - Migrate your data from your existing Google Apps account to your new Google Apps account
> - Delete your old Google Apps account
> - Add in `DomainA` as an alias to your new Google Apps account
>
> > **Important Note:**
> >
> > If you've already purchased a Google
> >     Apps for Business subscription for
> >     your current primary domain, you can't
> >     transfer your subscription to a new
> >     domain name. When you create a new
> >     Google Apps for Business account for a
> >     new domain name, you will be charged
> >     for each user account that you create.
> >     If you do not want to purchase Google
> >     Apps for Business for two separate
> >     domain names, disable automatic
> >     renewals on your current account and
> >     make the change at the end of your
> >     current subscription.
>
> The full steps for this process are:
>
> 1. Create a new account with the new primary domain.
>
>      
>     Sign
>      up  for and create a Google Apps account for your new domain name
>      at http://www.google.com/a/.
>     
>     The domain name must not be
>      associated with any existing Google Apps account. If it is associated
>      with an existing account, you must remove it before creating the new
>      account.
> 2. Migrate
>      your data to the new account.
>     
>     Use one of the email migration options to transfer
>      mail from accounts in your old domain to your new domain. Export
>      any documents, spreadsheets, and presentations you would like to
>      retain and upload
>      them into your new domain, or share them with a user account in the
>      new domain and copy them.
>     
>    Note: We do not offer migration
>      options for Google Sites. Instead we recommend that you use one of our
>      alternative methods to perform that function:
>
>    1. Create a
>         back up for the content in Docs and recreate the site once you
>         register with the new domain name.
>    2. Add the new domain admin
>         as owner of the site and then copy it inside of the new domain.
>    3. For those using the Sites API, you can go here for the migration
>         options that are available to you: http://code.google.com/p/google-sites-liberation/
> 3. Delete your old account.
>     
>     Once all
>      of your data has been transferred or backed up, delete
>      the Google Apps account for your old domain. It takes five days
>      for the account to be removed from our system.
> 4. (Optional) Add the previous primary domain to your new Google Apps
>      account. 
>     
>     If you want to retain the old primary domain as a
>      non-primary domain with access to your Google Apps functionality, add it to the new account.
>
> [1]: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=54819

Comment: But by doing so, that is, migrating to a new Google App. I lose the benefits of being an existing customer with Google. Taking into consideration that as of 10th May, 2011; any organisation that signs up for a new a/c will be required to use the paid Google Apps for Business product in order to create more than 10 users. This rule does not apply to the existing users. Their restriction will be based on the limit in place when they joined Google app. So, is there a better alternative or have Google updated their policies and have allowed us to change the primary domain?

Comment: This answer is obsolete at this time. See [Change your primary domain from the Admin console](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7009324?hl=en)

Answer (score 9):

This actually *is* possible. Basically, you need to add a secondary domain (not an alias) and then execute this Google Directory API request:

```
PUT
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customers/my_customer?fields=customerDomain&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
{"customerDomain": "my_new_domain.com"}`.
```

You can run this command quite easily, at the time of this writing, by visiting https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/customers/update, scrolling down to the "Try It" section, and setting `customerKey` to `my_customer`, `fields` to `customerDomain`, and adding the field `customerDomain` to the request body, with the value of your secondary domain that you'd like to make your primary domain (no www). Isn't that nice?

More detailed instructions are at http://www.saysjen.com/swapping-your-google-apps-primary-domain-to-your-secondary-domain-for-dummies/.

Comment: This is the correct answer and really should be an option provided by Google in Google Apps Admin.

Comment: Can an alias that already belongs to the same google apps account be switched with the primary domain using this method? I am getting a 403 error: Domain cannot use apis.

Comment: You must add it as a secondary domain, not an alias.

Comment: @antfx: Now is an option. See https://support.google.com/a/answer/7009324?hl=en

Comment: Why the down votes?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is as follows, you could move Domain B into a primary account of it's own. Google says it takes about 5 days move it but should be quicker, just check with customer support. 
Then you use Google Marketplace online tool http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=14156+5077282021820947710 to migrate Gmail, docs, calendar, contacts of all domain users to the new account in which Domain B is primary. Once this is done, you can let go of other domain A or set it up as an alias

Comment: Now it's possible to change the primary domain from the admin panel. See https://support.google.com/a/answer/7009324?hl=en