# Change primary domain on Google Apps without losing free account

Tags: google-workspace

I currently use my new domain as additional domain for my free Google Apps account but I actually would like to use it as the primary one. Unfortunately I read that it is only possible to change the primary domain by creating a new account. This would mean I would have to start paying for the account (I actually only use the mail function).

Is there a possibility to keep the free account but change the domain?

Comment: This actually *is* possible. I'd like to post as an answer, but I don't have the rep for it. Basically, you need to add a secondary domain (not an alias) and then execute this Google Directory API request: `PUT https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customers/my_customer?fields=customerDomain&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
{"customerDomain": "my_new_domain.com"}`. More details at http://www.saysjen.com/swapping-your-google-apps-primary-domain-to-your-secondary-domain-for-dummies/.

Comment: See my answer at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/86110/55243 for more info.

Comment: Someone wrote an article on how to do this: https://www.isaumya.com/how-to-change-primary-domain-for-google-apps-legacy-account/

Comment: @CharlieS As of early 2017, this is no longer an option: it is explicitly blocked by Google (even via the API) for Trial accounts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you already read from the Google [support](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=56198) pages:

> at this time you can't change which domain is your primary domain.

You can't do it. So there is no way of "keeping" your free Google apps plan if you insist on changing the primary domain. However, keeping the primary domain is not usually a problem if all you want to do is change the "Organization name". You can change the Organization name under `Domain Settings -> General`. Once you add the new domain name to the account you can also log in at `google.com/a/newdomainname.com`.

Comment: What if "primarydomain.com" expires, but linked "newdomain.com" does not?  Can you still continue to use newdomain?  IMHO discontinuing free GAFYD is just a really crap decision by google.  F them.

Comment: @g33kz0r I have an expired domain for 2 years as my primary domain. I can't receive emails from that domain obviously, but the account in general is fine.

Comment: You should be careful with that. If someone else registers your expired domain, they can use the CNAME records to reset account password and take control of your account. Related reading : http://techcrunch.com/2011/05/18/security-breach-heres-how-expired-domains-expose-you-to-embarrassment-and-theft/

Comment: The page now gives instructions on how to change the Primary domain with the Directory API, but this looks pretty advanced with no safety net.  Anyone tried this?

Comment: @MichaelCole As of early 2017, this is no longer an option: it is explicitly blocked by Google (even via the API) for Trial accounts.

Comment: 51% of software engineering is creating value.  49% is destroying it.

Answer (score 10):

If you use Google Apps Acounts with expired domains, the new owner can get the control of Google Apps Account.

Comment: What reference do you have to back this up?

Comment: technically this could be true.. the new owner of the domain would have to know what email address he will have to create though, although when you login with any email address from that domain google will already tell you what email the manager's is.

Comment: I usually do with my clients. https://support.google.com/a/answer/33561?hl=en You can reset your admin password with domain verification.

Comment: This is the direct url for domain verification: https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/DOMAIN.COM/VerifyAdminAccountPasswordReset

Answer (score 1):

I have running accounts where the primary domain is actually expired and use them via additional names and everything seems to work (for now).

Google is obviously "cleaning" old apps free accounts at the moment so perhaps they one day decide to check the primary domain against root domain server but I doubt they deactivate them if that account also includes active additional domain names.

By the way the "domains" feature is sort of "hidden" now under "More Tools" (bottom of screen) on the main icons admin screen.

Comment: As I posted in response to another comment above, If someone else registers your expired domain, they can use the CNAME records to reset account password and take control of your account. Related reading : http://techcrunch.com/2011/05/18/security-breach-heres-how-expired-domains-expose-you-to-embarrassment-and-theft/