# Google Apps...changing domains

Tags: google-workspace

A friend signed me up for a Google Apps account when it was free for a personal blog I planned to create. I no longer will be creating or maintaining a personal blog. I now want to use my free Google Apps account for a business domain that I own, AND I want to control the domain instead of bothering my buddy when I need help.

How do I transfer that account that was setup for me TO me, so I can take ownership of that free account and manage it myself for another domain. He is very busy now and I don’t want to keep bothering him. Like others who have asked, I want to maintain the free account too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the primary domain on Google Apps?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17064/how-can-i-change-the-primary-domain-on-google-apps) or [Change primary domain on Google Apps without losing free account](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44352/change-primary-domain-on-google-apps-without-losing-free-account)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Google intended to allow changing of the domain of a Google Apps account.

Nevertheless, I did hear of some one who added a new domain to his current Apps account, which I think can be either an Alias domain, which mean the same mailboxes for both domains, or as a separate domain, which means you can add mailboxes specifically for each one.

Look here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/182452?hl=en
And here: http://log.demaree.me/post/16979876647/two-domains-one-google-apps

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get control of the account, you need to set yourself up as administrator. If you still control the primary domain that the account was set up with, you can use a CNAME record change to recover the administrator password.

Once you have control, you can add your new domain name (can't change the primary) and set up users/apps accounts under your new domain name.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/33561?hl=en